# How to display different message box when meet condition

Tags: vba, excel, messagebox

I wish to display a different message box when it meet the following requirement:

1. When textbox8 value less than 3, message box will show textbox8 is out of range, do user want to continue store the data, if user hit yes, then will continue store the data but if user select no, will ask user to re-enter textbox8 value then only store data.
2. When textbox8 value is between 3 to 3.2, message box will show textbox8 is between 3 to 3.2, please be aware, and show a OK button for user to click and store the data.

I have try to add another message box inside but it will only check the first condition.

```
Sheets("Overall").Activate    
With Me
    If Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value) * Len(.TextBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox6.Value) * Len(.ComboBox6.Value) * Len(.TextBox7.Value) * Len(.TextBox8.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit"
    Else

        If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) < 3 Then
            If MsgBox("TextBox8 less than 3.0" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                      "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Exceeds") = vbNo Then

                MsgBox "user to re-type the value in TextBox8.", vbInformation, "Title"

                TextBox8.SetFocus

                          Else

        If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) >= 3 And CSng(.TextBox8.Text) <= 3.2 Then

        MsgBox "TextBox8 between 3 to 3.2, Aware!!!", , "Alert"


                  Exit Sub

         End If
         End If
         End If
        eRow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
               Cells(eRow, 11).Value = ComboBox5.Text
               Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Text
               Cells(eRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text
               Cells(eRow, 14).Value = TextBox6.Text
               Cells(eRow, 16).Value = ComboBox6.Text
               Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox7.Text
               Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox8.Text
               Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox9.Text

    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Please please please fix your indentation. Your `End If`s are *all over the place*. (and I'm guessing the root of your problem is their placement is incorrect...)

Comment: There is a `Exit Sub` appearing in the middle, and a lot of `End If`s. Can you please correct?

Comment: @shruti1810 Hi, I have correct it, sorry, because I still have few code to check others few on the top.
I have try to adjust the Exit Sub but it will save the data although I click on No to re-enter the value in textbox8

Comment: @Kimberly, it's still a bit messy. The IF, ELSE and END IF of the same clause should be indented to the same level. This also forces you to logically go through your conditions (and thereby helps find the problem)

Comment: @Kimberly, when you write an `If ... Then` statement it is good practice to write the `Else` and the `End If` lines at the same time *before* you type any code inside. This ensures that a) you remember to type them in, and b) you give them all the same indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code `If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) >= 3 And CSng(.TextBox8.Text) <= 3.2 Then` does not need to be within the `If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) < 3 Then` code block. If you change the code and fix your indentation, the code looks like:

```
    Sheets("Overall").Activate
    With Me
        If Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value) * Len(.TextBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox6.Value) * Len(.ComboBox6.Value) * Len(.TextBox7.Value) * Len(.TextBox8.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit"
        Else        ' If Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value)
            If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) < 3 Then
                If MsgBox("TextBox8 less than 3.0" & vbLf & vbLf & _
                          "Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Exceeds") = vbNo Then

                    MsgBox "user to re-type the value in TextBox8.", vbInformation, "Title"
                    TextBox8.SetFocus

                End If        ' If MsgBox("TextBox8 less than 3.0"
             End If        ' If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) < 3 Then

            If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) >= 3 And CSng(.TextBox8.Text) <= 3.2 Then

                MsgBox "TextBox8 between 3 to 3.2, Aware!!!", , "Alert"
                Exit Sub

            End If        ' If CSng(.TextBox8.Text) >= 3 And

            eRow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                   Cells(eRow, 11).Value = ComboBox5.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox4.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 8).Value = TextBox5.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 14).Value = TextBox6.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 16).Value = ComboBox6.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox7.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox8.Text
                   Cells(eRow, 19).Value = TextBox9.Text

        End If        ' If Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

If you find you have lots of `If` blocks in your code you can also add comments to the `Else` and the `End If` lines to show which `If` statement they belong to. I've done this in the code above.